# JPA EntityManager question

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence, entitymanager

I'm quite new to both JPA/Hibernate and to Java, and am having some trouble with the basics of using the EntityManager class to manage persistent objects.  I would appreciate it very much if someone would explain something very basic to me, because I can't figure it out from the documentation.

JPA 2 / Hibernate / Postgresql in a JSE environment.

*** Class definitions below ***

The following works as I would expect it to:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
Car corolla = new Car();
Part clutch = new Part();
clutch.setCar( corolla );
Part bumper = new Part();
bumper.setCar( corolla );
em.persist( corolla );
em.persist( clutch );
em.persist( bumper );
em.getTransAction().commit();
```

But this does not remove the links from the parts to the cars in the database:

```
tx.begin();
corolla.getParts().clear();
tx.commit();
```

Why is this the case?

Thanks in advance, and sorry if this is a silly question.

Mike.

Car class:

```
@Entity
public class Car {

private Long id;
private Set<Part> parts;

....

public Car() { parts = new HashSet<Part>(); }

@Id
@GeneratedValue( generator="increment" )
@GenericGenerator( name="increment", strategy = "increment" )
public Long getId() { return id; }
private void setId( Long id ) { this.id = id; }

@OneToMany( mappedBy="car", cascade=CascadeType.ALL )
public Set<Part> getParts() { return this.parts; }
public void setParts( Set<Part> parts ) { this.parts = parts; }

....

}
```

Part class:

```
@Entity
public class Part {

private Long id;
private Car car;

...

public Part() {};

@Id
@GeneratedValue( generator="increment" )
@GenericGenerator( name="increment", strategy = "increment" )
public Long getId() { return id; }
private void setId( Long id ) { this.id = id; }

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn( name="car_id" )
public Car getCar() { return this.car; }
public void setCar( Car car ) { this.car = car; }

...

}
```

Comment: The answer from axtavt (below), plus the bit about embedding the relationship in the object design in duffymo's answer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949427/is-it-necessary-to-call-a-flush-jpa-interface-in-this-situation helped me sort this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When sides of bidirectional relationship disagree, a state of the owning side (i.e. a side without `mappedBy`) is persisted to the database. So, you need to modify both sides consitently:

```
for (Part p: corolla.getParts()) {
    p.setCar(null);
}
corolla.getParts().clear();
```

Comment: The bit about the owning side being persisted is what I needed.  Thanks very much for this!

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine, however while removing an entity from your database you should be using:

```
EntityManager.remove
```

Comment: I don't think this is what I was looking for:  I don't want to remove the parts from the DB, but rather remove their association with the particular car.  Thanks, though :)