# Entitymanager.flush() VS EntityManager.getTransaction().commit - What should I prefer?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

What should I prefer when updating the database? What are the pros & cons with either method and when shall I use the one or the other?

```
public void disemployEmployee(Integer employeeId, Date endDate) {
    Employee employee = (Employee)em.find("Employee", employeeId);
    employee.getPeriod().setEndDate(endDate);
    em.flush();
}

public void disemployEmployee(Integer employeeId, Date endDate) {
    Employee employee = (Employee)em.find("Employee", employeeId);
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    employee.getPeriod().setEndDate(endDate);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In your first example, the changes to the data are reflected in database after encountering flush, but it is still in transaction.

But in second example, you are committing transaction immediately. Therefore the changes are made into the database & transaction also ends there.

Sometimes, flush may be useful to persist the data in between the ongoing transaction & then finally commit the changes afterwards. So you can also rollback the previous changes if there occurs some problem afterwards, like for batch insert/update.

Comment: In the first example there is no transaction, so there is an exception thrown at flush().

Comment: @DataNucleus I think in CMT, we don't have to start/end transaction manually.

Comment: sure but is he in CMT ? in his other example he starts the txn, so that is the only assumption I can make

Comment: @DataNucleus I presume in 1st case, transaction is implicitly commited & in 2nd its explicitly.

Comment: @NayanWadekar I don't think the data is send to the database. It's only in the cache. You need to "commit" to send data.

Comment: @TheProgrammer Which case are you referring. Do you mean that flush only caches data & not persisted, then it's wrong. Flush persists data, but isn't committed, can be rolled back.

Comment: @nayanwadekar I mean the first example. He only flushed but didn't commit which won't be loaded to the database.

Comment: @TheProgrammer No, changes are reflected immediately on flush, refer documentation - https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#flush() & here is some explanation about it - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17703822

Comment: @NayanWadekar then what about these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863725/how-we-can-get-jpa-entitymanager-flush-work, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275111/correct-use-of-flush-in-jpa-hibernate

Comment: @NayanWadekar Thanks for telling me about this. I appreciate it!

Comment: "Sometimes, flush may be useful to persist the data in between the ongoing transaction & then finally commit the changes afterwards." If flush immediatly changes db, why would I commit later?

Comment: @KorayTugay Read next line to it.

Answer (score 19):

According to the javadoc for `flush` and `commit`, `flush` is only for use **within** a transaction. It flushes (but doesn't commit), whereas commit commits data (obviously). They are distinct; there is no "preference" to be had.

The first example is wrong, and should result in an exception on calling flush (`TransactionRequiredException`).

Comment: What can I do with flush() that I cannot do without using flush()?

Comment: Flush puts the data in the datastore, and without it the data isn't there so queries can return data that is stale. Perhaps read the JPA spec on flush()

Comment: Well, everything the API says about flush() is "Synchronize the persistence context to the underlying database" and I have never used it before but my transactions still puts the data to database when calling `EntityManager.getTransaction.commit()`. And I have not called EntityManager.flush()! So I cannot understand the use of flush() when you can do everything it does even without it.

Comment: Yes indeed commit commits the data (as already said), and to do that, if it hasn't been flushed to the datastore then it does the flush. flush() simply gives you the option of putting it there earlier.

Comment: One use case for flush() is to force the generation of an ID you can use within the same transaction. For example, when you want to create logs (within the database) or history entries (basically copies). The reason not to use relationships between those entries and the actual entity in which case you don’t have to bother with the IDs is because you then couldn’t delete the entity without losing the log/history entry due to foreign keys.

Answer (score 5):

Both of your code samples doesn't persist or merge the entity state to be written to DB.

I don't think it appropriate to compare `EntityManager.flush()` and `EnityManager.EntityTransaction.commit()`.

flush() MUST be enclosed in a transaction context and you don't have to do it explicitly unless needed (in rare cases), when EntityTransaction.commit() does that for you.

Refer this link [Is it necessary to call a flush() (JPA interface) in this situation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949427/is-it-necessary-to-call-a-flush-jpa-interface-in-this-situation)

Refer this link [Question about flushing with JPA before a query is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415211/question-about-flushing-with-jpa-before-a-query-is-called) for a scenario to use flush()

Comment: As I asked DataNucleus: What can I do with flush() that I cannot do without using it?

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope the link answers your question.

Comment: @AhamedMustafaM `Both of your code samples doesn't persist or merge the entity state to be written to DB` No, if the entity is managed, the changes will be synchronized in the database implicitly.

Comment: @NayanWadekar Thank you for the new info. Let me analyze and remove it

Answer (score 0):

I would go for container managed transaction whenever possible. Bean managed transactions usually require significantly more code, because of the Exception possibilities. Also, it's more error prone (rollbacks, resource management).

That said, I would use a flush after the commit in container managed mode. That way I can catch possible PersistenceExceptions in my storage module and convert it to some more meaningful Exception for my use case module. This because I don't want to handle storage-specific Exceptions here, because I might swap the storage module out for something that does not use JPA... which never happened to me :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the missing part is, flush() just add to the datasources to be ready to commit, gives actual ids but not persist by default.

So if you need flush() to work as commit() you need to set the flush mode to Commit in the EntityManager by:

```
void setFlushMode(FlushModeType flushMode)
Set the flush mode that applies to all objects contained in the persistence context.
```

Note that FlushModeType is an enum that has these two values:

> FlushModeType AUTO (Default) Flushing to occur at query execution.
>   Since: JPA 1.0 FlushModeType COMMIT Flushing to occur at transaction
>   commit. The provider may flush at other times, but is not required to.
>   Since: JPA 1.0

I hope this help