# JPA Null or zero primary key encountered in unit of work clone

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jakarta-ee, jpa

I learn about `JPA` and had task to make database and insert some values to it. I wondered how I can find out what was the ID of recently inserted object, so I found a way that I need to use `flush` method of `EntityManager`.

Unfortunately I got the

> Null or zero primary key encountered in unit of work clone

exception when I use the above method. I think the problem lies in that my database has all `ID's` set on autoincrement ( **I use ORACLE 11G Express** ), so before commiting  it has `null` value and it rollbacks transaction.

**What I can do to fix it ?**

This is DB ( ID's are autoincrement[Sequences and Triggers in oracle]):
[image]

```
public class Client {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf =
                Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JpaIntroductionPU");        
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();

        et.begin();

        Address ad1 = new Address();
        ad1.setStreet("Skaraktki");
        ad1.setCode("64-340");

        em.persist(ad1);
        em.flush();

        System.out.println(ad1.getAId());
        et.commit();
    }   
}
```

> **Address class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Address.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM Address a"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Address.findByAId", query = "SELECT a FROM Address a WHERE a.aId = :aId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Address.findByStreet", query = "SELECT a FROM Address a WHERE a.street = :street"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Address.findByCode", query = "SELECT a FROM Address a WHERE a.code = :code")})
public class Address implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    // @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "A_ID")
    private BigDecimal aId;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "STREET")
    private String street;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "CODE")
    private String code;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "aId")
    private Employee employee;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "aId")
    private Department department;

    public Address() {
    }

    public Address(BigDecimal aId) {
        this.aId = aId;
    }

    public Address(BigDecimal aId, String street, String code) {
        this.aId = aId;
        this.street = street;
        this.code = code;
    }

    public BigDecimal getAId() {
        return aId;
    }

    public void setAId(BigDecimal aId) {
        this.aId = aId;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    public Department getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(Department department) {
        this.department = department;
    }       

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (aId != null ? aId.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Address)) {
            return false;
        }
        Address other = (Address) object;
        if ((this.aId == null && other.aId != null) || (this.aId != null && !this.aId.equals(other.aId))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "jpaintroduction.Address[ aId=" + aId + " ]";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to annotate your id field with [@GeneratedValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html), in order for JPA to know that the DB will generate the id automatically:

```
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "A_ID")
@SequenceGenerator( name = "mySeq", sequenceName = "MY_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1 )
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator="mySeq")
private BigDecimal aId;
```

With oracle you can use `GenerationType.IDENTITY` and `@SequenceGenerator` in which case you don't need a trigger to query the sequence and populate the ID, JPA will do it for you. I'm not sure if `GenerationType.AUTO` will work with oracle but if it does, you'd need a trigger to query the sequence and populate the id. `GenerationType.TABLE` is the most portable solution, since you use an independent table managed by JPA to store the sequence, it works across all databases.

Check the docs in the link above.

Comment: I needed to add the following line `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "SEQ_ADDRESS")`, all other combinations with `SEQUENCE`, `AUTO` etc. throw exceptions. I'm not sure is it working correctly or it's just an accident. For `AUTO` it throws `table or view does not exist`, for `SEQUENCE` - `The sequence named [SEQ_ADDRESS] is setup incorrectly.  Its increment does not match its pre-allocation size.` Could you maybe explain it to me please ? :P

Comment: sure, just edited, again, if you need more info there's plenty of documentation about this around. good luck.

Answer (score 19):

This happend to me because I manually added an entry to my database with the id 0 (zero).
In my case EclipseLink "couldn't" handle an id with zero.
So I added following to my persistence.xml:

```
     <property name="eclipselink.allow-zero-id" value="true"/>
```

This property says EclipseLink to handle zero as a valid id.

[1] http://meetrohan.blogspot.de/2011/11/eclipselink-null-primary-key.html

Comment: Thanks. This is the exact solution I was looking for. I had what @Camilo Bermudez suggested (GeneratedValue annotation) yet I started getting this error at the exact same time after I added a user in my DB with ID = 0.

Comment: This happened to me when using a *SEQUENCE*. [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6014.htm) starts with 1, but [HSQLDB](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch09.html#create_sequence-section) starts with 0.

Comment: This property is now deprecated. Use `<property name="eclipselink.id-validation" value="NULL"/>`

Comment: do you have any offical documentation about the deprecation?

Comment: @kdoteu sure, it is stated in javadoc: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.7/org/eclipse/persistence/config/PersistenceUnitProperties.html#ALLOW_ZERO_ID

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the problem lies in the fact that even when you commit a transaction, the Auto-increment function isn't invoked right away. Actually, while you are managing database interactions with the same EntityManager it won't.
My question would rather be: why are you persisting, then committing the transaction if you flush it anyway? Looks like duplicated code to me.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17703822/14373099) on flush.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28496051)

Comment: @GiulioCaccin This is an Answer. "the Auto-increment function isn't invoked right away. Actually, while you are managing database interactions with the same EntityManager it won't" is answering.

Comment: The question include code that can be involved in your answer. The link you referred also include code, i think it should be better for your answer to include relevant code, thus making your answer valid even if the link is down.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I'll keep it in mind ; I am still unused to the tooltip and was trying to keep the answer as short as possible.