# Getting null id after calling save, only after using @transactional in spring boot project

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

`

```
@Service
@Transactional

Public class UserService

public void saveUser()
    User userEntity = new User();
    userEntity.setName("test");
    User userDataFromDB =            userRepository.save(userEntity);
    LOG.info("user Id= " +userDataFromDB.getId());

//entity code below
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = 
GenerationType.IDENTITY)

@Column(name="ID")
private int id;

@Column(name="NAME")
private string name;`
```

not able to get the saved Id of user only after using transactional annotation else getting the id after removing transactional annotation . Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: please post your full code and not just a small snippet.

Comment: Post it from my mobile that is why I was able to written just the code snippet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change as below:

```
public void saveUser()
    User userEntity = new User();
    userEntity.setName("test");
    userRepository.saveAndFlush(userEntity); //force immediate db write
    LOG.info("user Id= " + userEntity.getId());
}
```

Typically database updates will not be flushed until your `@Transactional` method returns. By using `saveAndFlush(e)` (which delegates to `EntityManager#flush` 
 - [What does EntityManager.flush do and why do I need to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17703312/1356423)) you can force the database update to happen immediately.

As an aside, for or a newly persistent entity the `save(e)` or `saveAndFlush(e)` method calls simply return `e` so no need to assign the returned result to another variable.