# Execution Order of Flush() after a @Transactional method is executed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, flush

```
@Transactional
mymethod(){
    repo.saveAll(Large data);
    repo.save(small data); //updates db that the large data is written
}
```

**What I'm experiencing:**
After the transactional method's successful execution the two datas are flushed async. That is the small data is written before the large data.

**What I want:**
After the transactional method's successful execution the saveAll's data should be flushed first then the save's data should be flushed.

Is my understanding of, flush() of saveAll and save happening in async is correct? If yes, then how can I order the execution of flush of saveAll and save.

Comment: Can you test it so that you make two separate @Transactional methods and one method (not transactional) that call those new methods in the correct order?

Comment: can do that but it changes the logic. I don't want my status to be updated if there is any error in the first transactional method or save my data if there is any error in updating the status (second transactional method).

Answer (score 0):

i guess you set attribute of "small data" (for example smallData.setField1(value1)) earlier than "large data".

Comment: No. save() command is executed after saveAll(). But as it's within @Transactional both the data are written in the database together. But as the save() is small data it gets written first, which I don't want to happen.

Comment: if this is an update of existing record. you even don't need to call save(). hibernate will automatically execute update if you update any field. That's what i mean. do you call smallData.setSomeField(value1) earlier than largeData.setSomeField(value2)?

Comment: No. Large data is created and then only small data is updated

Answer (score 0):

In case of error, the transaction will be rollbacked and it's like the data hasn't be saved in the db. So it shouldn't matter in which order the two operations are executed ([assuming the transaction isolation in the database is configured correctly](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-transactional-propagation-isolation#transactional-isolations)). Hibernate, underneath, will pick the right order to execute the operations to make everything works.

But if it's really important for the `saveAll` to run before tha `save`, in the `JpaRepository`, there should be a method [saveAllAndFlush](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#saveAllAndFlush-java.lang.Iterable-):

```
@Transactional
mymethod(){
    repo.saveAllAndFlush(Large data);
    repo.save(small data); //updates db that the large data is written
}
```

The difference is that it it will flush the changes to the database without committing the transaction.

Comment: so regardless of the successful execution of "save(small data)", the "large data" will be flushed to the database right? Is there a way to wait for the transactional to complete and then flush saveAll() before save()

Comment: It doesn't matter if the query is executed on the db. The data won't be available until the transaction commits. If there is an error in `mymethod`, the transaction will be rollbacked and it's like you haven't executed the query at all.

Comment: one more doubt will the saveAllAndFlush happen in sync? Meaning with execution of save wait for the whole saveAll data to be flushed to the database?

Comment: I would expect that, otherwise how would you know that the saveAll is correct. It seems to me that you don't need to use it though. I've updated my answer

Comment: tried implementing with saveallandflush, but save(small data) is written before saveallandflush

Comment: Based on the info you gave us, that shouldn't happen. The actual code probably requires the operation to be executed in that order. Anyway, as I mentioned in my answer, it shouldn't matter because in case of error the transaction gets rollbacked.

Comment: I accept the execution happens in order, like the saveAllAndFlush starts its flush before executing the next save, but will it wait for that flush execution to complete?

Comment: It depends on how your entities are mapped. I can't say for sure based on the info you gave use. But, again, it shouldn't matter anyway.

Comment: No it matters. I get that it does not matter In view of transactional (rollback), but it matters because before the complete data is stored, the second command saves that progress as completed, which makes API calls return incomplete data.

Comment: Only if the transaction commits, the data is saved, otherwise changes won't remain in the db. And in case of error, the transaction shouldn't commit. Unless you are saying that your db is configured to see uncommitted data, I don't understand the problem,

Comment: I have largeD and smallD flushed. Now the transactional method finishes execution and commits. Now let's break down what happens inside commit. Does it store the largeD to the db and then store the smallD or both store happen async? My conclusion is it happens in async and I want them to happen in an orderly manner.

Comment: The order of the operations depends on how the entity are mapped. It's not async. If small data is saved first even with the flush, it means that the mapping you are using requires that. Based on the info you gave us, I don't think what you are doing makes sense. Anyway, good luck.

Comment: Just want to take a min to thank you for trying to help me this long. To give u some depth about the entity, the entity is not modified, list of new entities is created and saved. There is no relation between the largeD entity and smallD entity.

Comment: What happens if you remove `repo.save(small data)`? Does it still save the small data in the db?

Comment: No it doesnt save. As both the entity r not related, we have to save both explicitly

Comment: Even if they are not related, small data could be managed and it could be in the session and it would get saved during a flush. If small data is an unmanaged object, I cannot see any reason it will update the value in the db when you use `.saveAllAndFlush(large data)`. Clearly, there's some information missing.  I still think that it should not matter for your use case, but I guess it's always good to learn.

Comment: Is small data a completely new object? Like `SmallData sd = new Sd();`. And do you do something with it between the creation and `repo.save(sd)`?

Comment: No small object is getting updated

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. I'm asking how you get the small object. Can you rewrite  your code like this: `repo.saveAllAndFlush(large data); SmallData sd = loadSmallData(); repo.save(sd);`?

Comment: do u want in detail what happens in loadSmallData()

Comment: I guess... I just need to know if you are loading an existing value from the database or if you are creating a completely new object. Based on what you have said so far, you should be able to load it or create it after you've saved the large data (in the same transaction).