# Batch Insertion inJPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, openjpa

I have a question/confusion, how to do batch insert when records are in odd number say for example

```
batchSize = 20;
em.getTransaction().begin();
    for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++){
        Book book = new Book(i, "JPA Batch Insert Example: " + i);
        em.persist(book);

        if (i % batchSize == 0 && i > 0) {
            em.flush();
            em.clear();
        }
    }
    em.getTransaction().commit();
```

In this example 20 records will be inserted at once but what about rest 3 records what will happen to those 3 records , will it insert if yes then when

Comment: You need to add logic to insert and commit the odd bits left over.  Nothing is automatic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entitymanager.flush() VS EntityManager.getTransaction().commit - What should I prefer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048177/entitymanager-flush-vs-entitymanager-gettransaction-commit-what-should-i-p)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `em.getTransaction().commit();` in the end, this is what the Javadoc reads for `commit()`:

> Commit the current resource transaction, writing any unflushed changes
>   to the database.

So, it writes all the *unflushed* changes to database and commits the transaction. In your question, 3 records will be undflushed and will be written to database once `for` loop finishes.

Answer : You don't need to make any change to your code, it will automatically insert those 3 records (or any remaining records) once `for` loop is complete.